# How to make XMLHTTPRequest work properly on internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, upload, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11

So I am using XMLHttpRequest for uploading a file and checking it's upload state to make a simple progress bar.  It's working okay on Mozilla/Chrome/IE11  however sometimes I am returning from server to the user that he is not authorized to upload and then I am returning some String like "Not authorized". Firefox/Chrome handle it easy they just jump fairly fast to 100% upload progress and it's done. Internet Explorer Throws error :
XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ee2, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ee2.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#uploadProgressBar").css("opacity", "0");
  $("#fileForm").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#uploadState").text("Upload state: ");
    $("#uploadProgressBar").fadeTo(100, 1);
    var formData = new FormData($("#fileForm")[0]);
    $.ajax({
      xhr: function xhr() {
        $("#sss-upload").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#file-upload").attr("disabled", true);
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
          console.log(e)
          console.log(e.lengthComputable)
      console.log(xhr.readyState)
          if (e.lengthComputable) {
        console.log("EVENT LISTENER")
            var percent = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
            $("#uploadProgress")
              .attr("aria-valuenow", percent)
              .css("width", percent + "%")
              .text(percent + "%");
            if (percent == 100) uploadStateLoop();
          }
        }); //xhr.onload = uploadStateLoop;
    console.log(xhr.readyState)
        console.log("ADASDASDASDASDASDASDASDASDASDAS XHR UPLOAD")
        return xhr;
      },
      type: "POST",
      beforeSend: function beforeSend(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(
          "Authorization",
          "Basic " +
            window.btoa(getCookie("username") + ":" + getCookie("password"))
        );
      },
      url: "/edgeappupload",
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      error : function() {
            uploadStateLoop();
      },
      contentType: false
    });
  });
  $("#fileForm").on("change", "#sss-upload", function() {
    if ($("#sss-upload").get(0).files.length === 0) {
      $("#file-upload").attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $("#file-upload").attr("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

It's working normally on IE11 and on Firefox and Chrome when im authorized.

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps the issue is related to [the Ajax dataType and contentType property](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), from your description, you want to send parameters to the server and want to get the return data, so, it is better to add the Ajax dataType and contentType property, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url:url,
  type:"POST",
  data:data,
  contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(){
  ...
  }
});
```

Comment: dataType didn't change anything still the same problem, but thank's for an answer

Comment: So i believe when the server returns  string other browsers fast think that load has been done. But ie can't handle it and yiel timeout. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've added one more log into it here is the code.

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
          console.log(e)
          console.log(e.lengthComputable)
      console.log(xhr.readyState)
          if (e.lengthComputable) {
        console.log("EVENT LISTENER")
            var percent = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
            $("#uploadProgress")
              .attr("aria-valuenow", percent)
              .css("width", percent + "%")
              .text(percent + "%");
            if (percent == 100) uploadStateLoop();
        console.log("EVENT LISTENER END")
          }
```

And here is the output from console:

[Internet Explorer 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x1Xu.png)

[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l746C.png)

So in firefox It's pretty fast loading (nothing) because there is no privileges so it's returning a string. But in internet explorer, it ends on loaded: ~~3670016/94882688.
And throws this nasty error. And the server is just returning string "Not enough privileges for upload"